# Class implemented in multiple places

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode7

I'm using the Twitter API through Cocoapods in my iOS app.  It's being used in the app, a framework, and an app extension.  The project builds with no errors, but at runtime, I get this message:

> objc[27031]: Class TWTRScribeService is implemented in both
>   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TweetSave-cydxfgkrgtggufefrpvocnxaxelr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SaveKit.framework/SaveKit
>   and
>   ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3630AFBE-7C59-4574-8F44-9592A12DEF82/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D7A8F9C8-A39A-46DD-B737-A656415488F0/TweetSave.app/TweetSave.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

It repeats many times for a lot of the classes in the TwitterKit framework.

This is my Podfile:

```
def twitterkit_pods
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'TwitterCore'
end

target 'TweetSave' do
    pod 'Fabric'
    twitterkit_pods 
end

target 'SaveKit' do
    twitterkit_pods
end

target 'Saver' do
    twitterkit_pods
end
```

TweetSave is the app target, SaveKit is my framework, and Saver is an app extension.

What does this message mean and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Same issue using Firebase. Have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is linking in the SaveKit framework, which is what it looks like, then it will obtain all of the classes that way, and you can remove twitterkit_pods from the the application target.

Answer (score 1):

You have statically linked the same classes into both the app and framework and the runtime linker is confused about which one to use.  It will decide for itself which to use and is warning you of this fact.

I think the only way to solve this is to dynamically link `TwitterLink.framework`, if that's possible, however as it's designed to work in an iOS app it's probably a static framework.  I therefore cannot see any easy was out of this issue.